# Full disk encrypted linux + windows

Tags: debian, windows, dual-boot, encryption

I like to install windows7 with dual boot. I have a linux on my disk with full luks/dm encryption. My question is,  can i install windows in this encrypted disk? i can shrink 50-100gb and like keep linux and all. It is possible?

Comment: Consider another approach: Install Windows in a virtual machine with Linux as host. Then all your files are encrypted. VirtualBox is easy to use.

Comment: I know virtualbox, but this case is not good for me. i dont like to virtualise.

Comment: [Windows/Linux dual boot full disk encryption](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/366437/44425)

Answer (score 1):

Windows does not support LUKS containers and booting from it natively.
You can use LibreCrypt to access such containers, but i don't think it is possible to install and use windows entirely from LUKS container.